# Limit dante socks connections based on username

Tags: linux, proxy, socks, dante

I have created a dante socks server with the following simple configuration:

```
debug: 0
logoutput: stderr
internal: 0.0.0.0 port = 1080
external: eth0
socksmethod: username
clientmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: sockd

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    command: bind connect
    log: connect disconnect error
    socksmethod: username
    protocol: tcp
}
```

I want to know is there anyway to limit the socks connection based on username on dante 1.4?
It seems dante 1.3 has such a functionality but version 1.3 is not supported anymore! I could find limiting connection based on sessions on dante 1.4,  but it limits the overall sessions or per IP address. I want to limit the connections based on usernames not the IP address.